# My set up is MiKTeX and TeXStudio

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I have installed MiKTeX and I have been installing the needed packages through MiKTeX package manager.

At first it was installing the missing packages but some had error couldn't install. There after while installing further packages MiKTeX stopped working and required online solution.

I tried but didn't work out. Then this led to even TeXStudio to stop working. I tried to uninstall MiKTeX refused to be uninstalled, demanding solution from online.

Please any help, what can I do to solve this serious problem to me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What kind of installation do you have? Basic installer and shared installation or only for the user?

Comment: It is better to provide screenshots of your installation steps to find where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems you have now a real faulty system.  It seems to be the best to delete the old installation completly and reinstall it.

Please do the following:

1. Reboot the computer
2. Use the control panel to delete the faulty MiKTeX
3. Download the current installer from MiKTeX homepage (I suggest to use the net installer to get the complete MiKTeX!)
4. Start the installer.  Check that the download has been finished without errors. If there was an error just restart the installer.  The installer checks which files are needed and so it goes on with downloading not jet downloaded files. It could be, if you have a bad or slow internet connection that you have to restart it several times! (One student of mine needed 13 restarts!)
5. Check that the download is finished without errors and complete.
6. Reboot the computer
7. Now install MiKTeX with restarting the installer for installation (check the right button).  Check that it finished without errors. If needed, restart the installer.
8. Reboot the computer
9. If TeXStudio now does not find the installed MiKTeX uninstall it and install TeXStudio again (I do not use this editor, but it should be able to see that MIKTeX is installed and should be able to configure itself correctly).